# how can i use different jdk for run and compile on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I want to use zuluJDK for compile and AdoptJDK for run because of some reason.

but I can not find a way.

I've seen how to set compiler on Intellij web site. but there is no way to use different jdk for compile.

Even if i do not use IntelliJ, please let me know if there is a way to use other jdk in compiling and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean compile with zuluJDK and run with AdoptJDK?

1. open project structure settings(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) and change sdk to zuluJDK
2. make jar or war file to run (compile and package)
3. run jar as cmd with AdoptJDK

e.g.

```
cd C:\Program Files :: x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin (AdoptJDK installed folder where include java.exe
java -jar packged.jar
```